# Squash or minimize an event log

Tags: event-sourcing

I am looking for a way to minimize an event log into bare minimum number of events to recreate the latest state. To give an example, if the following list of events represent everything that have happened in a simple Todo-application:

```
TodoCreated(1)
TodoTextUpdated(1,"Buy milch")
TodoCreated(2)
TodoTextUpdated(1,"Buy milk")
TodoRemoved(2)
```

I don't want that all of the my consumers see all the intermediate steps and I would like to minimize them into just the following events

```
TodoCreated(1)
TodoTextUpdated(1,"Buy milk")
```

Both list of events would result in the same end state.

Does it exist a general algorithm for this or do you have to program this case by case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that you need to handle on a case by case basis.

Modifying events is contrary to the spirit of what event sourcing is intended to be.  This is especially the case when you get out of CRUD domains, and start working with domain events that have actual business semantics.

BUT

Nobody said that you have to share the "real" event stream with your clients.  You could, for example:

1) build up the current state of the object after each batch of events, and share with the clients the "latest" state, without the history behind it.

2) read a batch of events, calculate the change, and publish a patch event on the client stream

3) Censor events out of the client stream (they can see some of what's going on, but not enough to actually recreate the object state.
4) Attempt a reconciliation and merge, as you hinted at originally.

You might want to review Greg Young's talk on [Occassionally Connected](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1980-cqrs-not-just-for-server-systems) systems.  In it, he sketches an approach to comparing events to detect conflicting commands.  You would want something similar, to detect which events in your system are covered/hidden by a separate event.  In Greg's example, they got a lot of business value out of the work they did here, so maybe it's worth considering.